# Python shows No such file or directory Error though the file exists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to search a string from multiple files

**What I tried:**

```
import os
path= 'sample1/nvram2/logs' 
all_files=os.listdir(path) 
for my_file1 in all_files:
    print(my_file1)
    with open(my_file1, 'r') as my_file2:
        print(my_file2)
        for line in my_file2:
            if 'string' in line:
                print(my_file2)
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\user1\scripts>python search_string_3.py
abcd.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search_string_3.py", line 6, in <module>
    with open(my_file1, 'r') as my_file2:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abcd.txt'
```

But file abcd.txt is present in C:\Users\user1\scripts\sample1\nvram2\logs

Why the Error shows that No such file or directory?

**Using glob:**

The following error was displayed when I use `all_files=glob.glob(path)` instead of `all_files=os.listdir(path)`

```
C:\Users\user1\scripts>python search_string_3.py
sample1/nvram2/logs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search_string_3.py", line 7, in <module>
    with open(my_file1, 'r') as my_file2:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'sample1/nvram2/logs'
```

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `with open(my_file1, 'r') as my_file2:`, why do you expect that it should look in the `C:\Users\user1\scripts\sample1\nvram2\logs` folder for the file?

Comment: "The following error was displayed when I use all_files=glob.glob(path)" - notice how the output of the `print(my_file1)` line is different?  That should point to a misunderstanding of what the `glob` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you figured out/guessed the first issue. Joining the directory with the filename solves it. [A classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065027/cant-open-files-from-a-directory-in-python):

```
with open(os.path.join(path,my_file1), 'r') as my_file2:
```

I wouldn't have cared to answer if you didn't attempt something with `glob`. Now:

```
for x in glob.glob(path):
```

since `path` is a directory, `glob` evaluates it as itself (you get a list with one element: `[path]`). You need to add a wildcard:

```
for x in glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"*")):
```

The other issue with `glob` is that if the directory (or the pattern) doesn't match anything you're not getting any error. It just does nothing... The `os.listdir` version crashes at least.

and also test if it's a file before opening (in both cases) because attempting to open a directory results in an I/O exception:

```
if os.path.isfile(x):
  with open ...
```

In a nutshell `os.path` package is your friend when manipulating files. Or [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) if you like object-oriented path manipulations.